# OutOfMemoryException after looping 500K records

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

This code results in an error

> System.OutOfMemoryException

```
Using VT As New BidiEntities  
    For Each dr In Bidis

        Dim hkBidi As New hkBidi
        hkBidi.UserId = Userx
        VT.AddTohkBidis(hkBidi)
    Next    
   *VT.SaveChanges()*    
End Using
```

`VT.SaveChanges()` results in this error when looping through 500,000 records.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: What is `BidiEntities`? Is that an Entity Framework data context?

Comment: Yes, it is entity framework data context

Comment: Thank you for editing p.campbell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this method. competent_tech and p.campbell thanks! :)

```
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim uList As New List(Of hkBidi)

        For Each dr In Bidis
            i += 1

            uList.Add(New hkBidi With {.UserId = dr.UserId})

            If i > 9999 Then
                i = 0
                BidiSave(uList)
                uList.Clear()
            End If
        Next
' Up to 500000 if the (sample 502500) and smaller than 10000
        If uList.Any() Then
            BidiSave(uList)
        End If
```

-

```
Public Sub BidiSave(uList As List(Of hkBidi))
    Using VT As New BidiEntities
        For Each dr In uList
            VT.AddTohkBidis(dr)
        Next
        VT.SaveChanges() ' No Problem
    End Using ' No Exception
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to store 500,000 records and are getting an out of memory exception doing so, then you need to restructure your loop to perform the SaveChanges every x records, where x is some value that doesn't cause the exception (i.e. 10,000).

This will make your code slightly more complex, but performant:

```
Dim wCount As Integer
Const MAX_LOOPS As Integer = 10000
Dim VT As BidiEntities

Try
    For Each dr In Bidis
        If VT Is Nothing Then 
           wCount = 0
           VT = New BidiEntities
        End If

        Dim hkBidiAs New hkBidi
        hkBidi.UserId = Userx
        VT.AddTohkBidis(hkBidi)

        wCount = wCount + 1
        ' When we reach the maximum number of loops, save the changes, then dispose the VT Object and set it to nothing
        If wCount >= MAX_LOOPS Then
            VT.SaveChanges()
            VT.Dispose()
            VT = Nothing
        End If
    Next
Catch
   ' Do something with the exception
Finally
    ' Handle the records added in the last loop, if any
    If VT IsNot Nothing Then
        VT.SaveChanges()
        VT.Dispose()
        VT = Nothing
    End If
End Try
```